# How to add a rule to an existing KnowlegeBase Drools 5.3?

Tags: drools, rules

How to Dynamically add rules to Drools 5.3, I am using this version and could not find an appropriate answer for the same, I have seen the answer for drools 6 but that's of no use to me because the API has changed.

In the API I see how to remove a rule from the KnowlegeBase but could you help me out how to add rule at runtime.

Comment: This depends on what kind of session you are running - stateful or stateless. Also, how do you want to notify the application of the addition of the rule - should it monitor the file system, or should it react to an alert message. There's no such method as "bingoNewRule".

Comment: No I don't want to notify the user, I just want to add dynamically the rule into my session. Also I am a bit confused what really is the difference between a stateful and a stateless session can you please help out ? According to my findings a stateless session contains stateful session in it's implementation so when to use one over the other.